# How to find element and get element that follows that element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html structure

```
<div class="block">
    <span>
        <span class="location">::before</span>
        <a href="example.com">New York</a>
    <span>
    <span>
        //some other elements
    </span>
    //n number of spans
</div>
```

I need to find where is `span` with class `location` and get `a` element, particularly its text content, i.e. **New York**. 
The problem is the span with the class `location` may be in n-th span, so I need to find it, and then get following anchor.

Comment: Did you try with queryselectorall('.location') or withqueryselector('.location')...?

Comment: Is the anchor **always** the next html element after `span.location`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
let city = $('span.location').first().next().text()
```

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b01kxuwe/).

It uses an element query to find `<span>` elements with the `location` class, then `.first()` to limit it to a single matching `<span>`, then `.next()` to traverse to the next sibling, then finally `.text()` to get the element text.

Answer (score 1):

Siblings can be a tough one. Here is a codepen that uses the adjacent selector. [Support looks](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2) ok as well for regular css selection but definitely works in jQuery element targeting

[codepen w/adjacent selector](https://codepen.io/dimstar7/pen/QzmGVm)

```js
$('span.location + a').text();
```